# Objective-C. Create file at path which doesn't exist?

Tags: objective-c, directory, exists, file-exists, createfile

For example if I want to write file.txt into /folder1/folder2/folder3/ and noone of folders exists.

Is it the only way to create them manually?

Comment: manually or programatically?

Comment: I meaned programmatically but substring each path for each folder and even check if each path doesn't exist then create this folder. Or can I do it simplier?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try that it should do the job:

```
    NSString * yourPath = @"/folder1/folder2/folder3";
    NSError * error = nil;
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath: yourPath 
                                             withIntermediateDirectories:YES 
                                                              attributes:nil 
                                                                   error:&error];
    if (!success)
      NSLog(@"Error");
    else
      NSLog(@"Success");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will help you:

```
-[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtPath%3awithIntermediateDirectories%3aattributes%3aerror%3a) with YES in the intermediate directories parameter to create all the folders you need in the path.